# How to convert a random string to a byte string

Tags: julia

I generated a random string lets say using this `randstring(RandomDevice(), 'a':'z', 15)` Now I want its output as a byte string. How do I do that?

More context: What I am trying to do is to write something similar to python's os.urandom() function.

Comment: Where does  `RandomDevice` comes from?

Comment: I don't get the question? it comes from the standard lib but are you asking why I have used it? @SalchiPapa

Comment: Sorry  I opened an old interpreter and it tripped me up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia doesn't seem to have Python like *bytestrings* at least in `Base`.

```rb
julia> using Random    

julia> using Random: RandomDevice, randstring

julia> rs = randstring(RandomDevice(), 'a':'z', 15)
"wbfgxgoheksvxvx"
```

You can get a code units wrapper using the  `codeunits` function, which returns a vector of `Base.CodeUnits`:

```rb
julia> cu = codeunits(rs)
15-element CodeUnits{UInt8,String}:
 0x77
 0x62
 0x66
 0x67
 0x78
 0x67
 0x6f
 0x68
 0x65
 0x6b
 0x73
 0x76
 0x78
 0x76
 0x78
```

Or with the `b""` non standard string literal macro:

```rb
julia> b"wbfgxgoheksvxvx"
15-element CodeUnits{UInt8,String}:
 0x77
 0x62
 0x66
 0x67
 0x78
 0x67
 0x6f
 0x68
 0x65
 0x6b
 0x73
 0x76
 0x78
 0x76
 0x78
```

You can have a byte array like this:

```rb
julia> ba = Vector{UInt8}(rs)
15-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x77
 0x62
 0x66
 0x67
 0x78
 0x67
 0x6f
 0x68
 0x65
 0x6b
 0x73
 0x76
 0x78
 0x76
 0x78
```

You could use the `repr` function, along with `split` and `join` functions to create your desired string:

```rb
julia> function bytestring(s::String)::String
           ba = Vector{UInt8}(s)
           return join([join(("\\x", split(repr(cu), "x")[2]), "") for cu in ba], "")
       end
bytestring (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bytestring(rs)
"\\x77\\x62\\x66\\x67\\x78\\x67\\x6f\\x68\\x65\\x6b\\x73\\x76\\x78\\x76\\x78"
```

You can put that in a macro in order to create a custom non standard string literal:

```rb
julia> macro bs_str(s)
           return bytestring(s)
       end
@bs_str (macro with 1 method)

julia> bs"wbfgxgoheksvxvx"
"\\x77\\x62\\x66\\x67\\x78\\x67\\x6f\\x68\\x65\\x6b\\x73\\x76\\x78\\x76\\x78"
```

Finally you could compose it like this:

```rb
julia> urandom(r::Random.AbstractRNG, chars, n::Integer)::String = bytestring(randstring(r, chars, n))
urandom (generic function with 1 method)

julia> urandom(RandomDevice(), 'a':'z', 15)
"\\x67\\x61\\x78\\x64\\x71\\x68\\x73\\x77\\x76\\x6e\\x6d\\x6d\\x63\\x78\\x68"
```

Comment: oh no sorry, I messed up my title, I meant byte string not byte array like this  b"DATA\xff\u2200" @SalchiPapa